# tkinter Text widget support Farsi (Arabic) letters in ubuntu

Tags: python, tkinter, arabic-support, farsi, tkinter-text

I have a Text widget in Ubuntu 22.04 and I want to write Farsi in it but it not work properly with Farsi letters, I used add_bidi_support from  awesometkinter lib but for entry widget ,the library does not have any function for Text widget.

```
description_text = tk.Text(record_tab, width=15,height=5 ,font=("B Nazanin",20))
description_text.tag_config('tag-right', justify='right')
description_text.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYWCe.png)

it has to be like this : سلام

I tried

awesometkinter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have use the `Tkinter.Text.tag_config` method. However, I am not sure if your Arabic characters `salam` has configured as the `tab-right`. If your word is out-of-tag, the font request will be ignored.

Let say simplier. You fired up a Word document. You typed text inside it and then set the blank line into different font. You won't see your text changing the font too. That's the same theory.

Then, how to solve this problem? Easy. Add a tag to it.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Misinahaiya's solution")

record_tab = ttk.Notebook(root)
record_tab.pack(expand=True)

description_text = tk.Text(record_tab, width=15, height=5, font=("B Nazanin", 20))
description_text.insert("1.0", "سلام")
description_text.tag_add("tag-right", "1.0", tk.END) # <- MAIN POINT!!!
description_text.tag_config('tag-right', justify='right')
description_text.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: steel have the same problem on Ubuntu
it is س ل ا م